# How to make it so that SpeechSynthesis avoids emojis in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, speech, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

I have this JavaScript for performing `SpeechSynthesis`

```
let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello world! ");
speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

**which works!**

However, I have this slight problem that the string `"Hello World! "` contains an emoji  and when the `SpeechSynthesis` happens it actually **speaks out the emoji**, i.e. it would say "Hello world waving hand".

Is there any way for it to filter out that  `waving hand` from its speech?

*Do note that the provided string contains  and I have to try my best not to filter it out of the string itself but only from the speech.*

Comment: Filter it out of the string before speaking it--it's not like you'd be modifying the original string anyway.

Comment: "*I have to try my best not to filter it out of the string itself but only from the speech.*" why?

Comment: @VLAZ It's a third-level (i.e., slightly important) part of the coding challenge, I can get extra points by doing that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Alright, I'll do that since that seems like the only way right now. You can put that as an answer and then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to do this so the only solution was just to filter out the emoji from the string.

Here it goes:

```
let toSpeak = "Hello World ";
toSpeak = toSpeak.replace('','');
let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(toSpeak);
speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```